# Execution flow of MPI

Tags: c, mpi

How come the control jumps from MPI_Send() at if block straight to MPI_Recv() in else if.
As far as decision making conditions are concerned it should only execute a single block of code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int number = 54;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &no_of_process);
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_rank);
    MPI_Status status;
    if (process_rank == 0) {
        MPI_Send (&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else if (process_rank == 1) {
        MPI_Recv (&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, in short it shouldn't execute both blocks in a single thread, but it may _seem_ like it does if there are multiple processes or threads involved. Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer this question without seeing code. The first difficulty is in understanding your question properly.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I've edited my question with a simple code, hope this helps in understanding what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: And @Hristo's answer is still good.

Comment: Hope this is just a fragment of the code as it is missing a call to `MPI_Finalize()` before the end of `main()` and is thus not a correct MPI application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The execution model of MPI is either SPMD (Single Program Multiple Data) or MPMD (Multiple Programs Multiple Data) with SPMD being more widespread. In this execution model, from the single source code one produces a binary file from which then multiple instancies, known as processes, are started. Each instance has its own identifier known as *rank* and different branches of the code are executed based on the rank. So the `MPI_Send` is executed by one rank ("rank" is usually used as the short version of "a process with a given rank") while the `MPI_Recv` is executed by another rank and if the `MPI_Send` specifies the rank of the process that has executed the `MPI_Recv`, then the message is sent between the two. MPI also allows for message buffering and non-blocking operations so one rank can also talk to itself.

So usually if a conditional, based on the rank is imposed, there are some processes where it is satisifed and there are processes where it isn't. Thus both branches get executed but in different processes and possibly at different times.

Programming in MPI requires a bit of a split personality thinking and it usually takes some time to get used to.

Comment: to extend my comment above, ... but @HristoIliev pulls off a good answer to a badly-formed question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I've just got back my crystal ball from the repair shop. I'm so glad it works!